# Angular 4 routing: navigate to home page

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular4-router

I have the following routes defined:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '**', component: HomeComponent }

];
```

Accessing `www.mysite.com` displays my `HomeComponent` which is fine. But when I click my menu link to navigate back to the homepage it takes me to `www.mysite.com/home`

Link code below:

```
<a href="home" [routerLink]="['home']" class="nav-link active">Home</a>
```

How can I make this link navigate to the main url `www.mysite.com`?

Comment: Can you try `<a href="home" [routerLink]="['/']" class="nav-link active">Home</a>`

Comment: tried, it's the same result :(

Answer (score 2):

You need to add route with empty string see example below

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
  { path: '**', component: HomeComponent }
];
```

In angular [docs](https://angular.io/api/router/Route#properties) it's mentioned under property heading:

> path?: string  The path to match against. Cannot be used together with
>   a custom matcher function. A URL string that uses router matching
>   notation. Can be a wild card (**) that matches any URL (see Usage
>   Notes below). Default is "/" (the root path).

and then update the link to:

`<a href="home" [routerLink]="['/']" class="nav-link active">Home</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the `home` route, and your link points to `/home`, so the behavior is what you told Angular to do.

If you want to navigate to `/`, change the html with `<a [routerLink]="['/']" class="nav-link active">Home</a>`.

Also, you have to change your routing config:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' } // patchMath is important with empty route, otherwise any route would match
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' } // so if you want to access "/foo123", the url will change to "/", so the user wouldn't see a non existing url in the address bar.
];
```